# How to make formatException gone in Datetime

Tags: c#

Hi I just want to know how to make formatException gone when I'm inserting Datetime.

coding is in down below:

```
DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(z);
dob.ToString("yyMMdd");
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
today.ToString("yyMMdd");
var year = today.Year - dob.Year;
age = Convert.ToString(year);
return a;
```

Comment: The exception is well documented. It means that the string you passed does not represent a valid `DateTime` value. In some cases, the string is completely unparseable. You can use `Try...()` methods to detect these cases without an exception being thrown. In other cases, the string is parseable but not using a standard format. In those cases, use `TryParseExact()` or `ParseExact()` and pass the correct format for the string you want to parse. In some cases, the string is valid in a culture different than the current one. In those cases, pass the right culture to the parse method. See dupes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method to convert your date string `z` to a `DateTime` value -

```
var z = "23/09/2020";

DateTime dob = DateTime.ParseExact(z, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

As you can see, you have to pass the date format you are trying to convert to the second parameter of the `ParseExact()` method as a string;

Comment: okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

Try use [DateTime.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) to check your datetime string and store to your variable after parse at the same time

Comment: will try it later